# How can I use another OTF font from the system with kpfonts-otf just for a short text

Tags: fonts, fontspec, opentype, kpfonts

I wanted to add a short sentence in, let's say, Garamond o some scripted font, to my book.  How can I? I now it is not possible to use `fontspec`

Comment: why can't you use fontpec? which tex engine are you using?

Comment: Something like `\fontspec{EBGaramond-Italic.otf}{some text}` should do the trick. See the `fontspec` manual for more.

Comment: You both are absolutely right.  I had a lot of problems with scrbook+Luatex+kpfonts… and later I updated everything to the latest version, now I'm doing it with every new update of the involved (many) packages.  It works!  what a relieve!  Thanks!